# How to add model objects "to cart" in django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to work out how to use a very simple bit of "shopping cart" functionality, but I'm no good at this.

Let's say I have a simple queryset, "objectos" that comes from:

```
# models.py:
class ObjectModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...
    content = models.TextField()


# views.py
def product_list(request):
    objectos = ObjectModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'frontpage/object_list.html', {'objectos':objectos})
```

..And let's say I need to insert a simple button in the template that grabs an object from the queryset and puts the object in another queryset. This is what I can't figure out; how to do that secondary queryset..

Anyway, here's a simplified look at what I'm trying to do in the template:

```
<!-- template -->
{% for obj in objectos %}
  {{ obj.title }}
  {{ obj.content }}
  <a href="#">
    <button type="button">add to other qs!</button>
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```

How could this be done in a simple fashion?

I'm considering building a shopping cart, only a lot simpler, but I'm not sure that's the right way to approach it. If you coulddirect me to a good shopping cart tutorial or similar that I could look at, I'd be most grateful :)

Comment: What do you mean by "grabs an object from the queryset and puts the object in another queryset"?

Comment: Well, say you have 5 objects in one set; apples, oranges, bananas, pears and grapes, but you only want to see apples and grapes. I guess you could call it a subset of the original qs, if that helps? :)

Comment: i see! Check out the answer I provided. It is a great tutorial which should answer your question, and show you more tricks to help you get your shopping cart done faster and better!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways you can do this, but the best way would be to follow a tutorial which has easy steps to follow and explains throughout the way. I did some research, and this looks like a great tutorial which has multiple pages, each one explaining a different part of building a simple shopping cart.

https://blog.muva.tech/lesson-1-building-e-commerce-shopping-cart-using-django-2-0-python-3-6/

Comment: Ah, I've already been to that one and I regret to say that the web page breaks at lessons 4 through 7. Other than that it was all right, I reckon. I'm trying my luck with a long and old video tutorial from CFE at the moment, see if that works :)